# Storing small amounts of dynamic data on website

Tags: php, database

Try to imagine a site with a greeting or catch phrase that is shown on a home page that can be edited or changed by the site owner. What is the best way to store small amounts of data like that? I am currently using a database to store very complex data, but it seems very wasteful to make a whole new table just so that i can store and retrieve a single row.

What are good practices for such use cases? If it is of any use, I'm currently using a LAMP stack with a Laravel framework

Comment: As I see it you only have one other option if you don't want to use database. A text file.

Comment: but would you suggest using a database for this if my site already leverages a database? Im primarily asking because I want to get some opinions out there on these situations. Can you give me your 2 cents on the best course of action?

Comment: yes database if your site already uses one

Comment: What is your definition of "wasteful"?  A db table is (basically) only as big as the data it holds.  So it's not like you're "reserving" 1gb of space and only storing 1mb in it.

Comment: @PatrickQ I have to confess, I m not sure why it would be wasteful but my hunch just assumes that there would be much more infrastructure work going into making a new table and keeping it there than say making a new text file as Andreas said

Comment: I agree with cmorrissey. Text files has a issue in php, they can't be used by two sessions at the same time. So if two people load the page at the same time it could happen that the file content is deleted. And because of that, I say database. /from someone who still use text files himself

Comment: If you still want to use textfiles use `$text = file_get_contents("file.txt");` to read it to variable. And file_put_contents to save to it.

Comment: @Andreas I think you just provided a selling point against files. Thank you. Ill keep using my database

Comment: @Andreas please log your comment as an official answer. Id like to tick that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it you only have one other option if you don't want to use database. A text file.

I agree with cmorrissey. Text files has a issue in php, they can't be used by two sessions at the same time. So if two people load the page at the same time it could happen that the file content is deleted. And because of that, I say database.

If you still want to use textfiles use $text = file_get_contents("file.txt"); to read it to variable. And file_put_contents to save to it.

Comment: Keep in mind when I say same time, I really mean same time. It's not often it happens.

Answer (score 2):

If you already use a database, I don't see why it would be wasteful to store this in it. Alternatively, you can have a config file in json, yaml or any type you prefer and read the data from there. However, your client probably can manage the data easier if you use the database and provide the option to change it in an admin area.